# PHP JSON encoding and emoji

Tags: php, json, emoji

I have a JSON response like this

```
{
  "status": "\ud83d\ude0e"
}
```

I need to convert it using PHP in `1f60e`, any suggestions?

Comment: What output do you get? And what is your code for getting that output? When I `json_decode` that string I get the smiley as expected...

Comment: 1f60e is emoji unicode version, i need it

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode()` should decode to Emoji

```
<?php
  $json = '{"status": "\ud83d\ude0e "}';
  $obj = json_decode($json);
  echo $obj->{'status'};
?>
```

Result: http://goo.gl/7Ba2XJ